# Split text area into array

Tags: javascript

I have a text area field and I need to get all the values, then split them into array.

[image]

Here is my code: `sample.split('\n')`

When I review the logs, I've observed that there are spaces in them...

`[133986 ,133979 ,133981 ]`

How can I remove the spaces when I split it?

Thank you.

Comment: Spaces? I don't see any. Do you mean commas?

Comment: @squint - There are spaces in the first two elements between the last number and the comma.

Comment: @newbie: It really helps if you post text instead of images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var arr = sample.split('\n').map(function(element){
  return element.trim();
});
```

Comment: is there a way using regex?